# Starting a Flask webservice before a test gitlab-ci

Tags: python, flask, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run a gitlabci test on my flask server

```
image: ubuntu:18.04
stages:
    - test
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
    - pip3 install requests
    - pip3 install flask
    - cd src
    - python3 -m app.py
    - python3 -m unittest test
```

When I run this test on gitlab I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'app.py' (AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute '__path__')
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

the test.py file relies on the Flask app.py webservice to be running. The webservice must not be running when the test is carried out.

**app.py**

```
...



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8006)
```

I have tried these tests **locally** and get the correct response (app.py running locally):

### `PS /test.py
......

Ran 6 tests in 0.029s

OK`

Example test requiring app.py

```
#Test Correct HTTP Response Code on No Params
def test_total_http_fail_rc(self):
    URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8006"
    response = requests.get(URL)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 400)
```